# Is there a way to view the actual code in Construct 2?

Tags: construct-2

While I was using Construct 2, I decided I wanted to see what the code that the events were creating looked like. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You have to export your project in order to view the final JavaScript.

Ashley from Scirra wrote in a similar topic:

> Many users are worried about reverse-engineering, so the exported Javascript code is deliberately obfuscated and difficult to work with.

Comment: Note that the code is only obfuscated if you set up and run the Minifier when you export.  If you skip that step because you don't have a Java SDK installed, your code will be easily readable by default and more easily reverse-engineered/stolen.